# trying to print mulitple logistic regressions in statsmodels python

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to print a series of logistic regressions in statsmodels but am unsure how to print the results to something other than the console screen. I've created a function that runs the regressions where data is the dataset, and the other variables are a series of lists of dummy variable labels from the dataset (i'm sure its not the most efficient way to run though these, but it works, and made sense when I have 5 dependent variables that I want to run regressions for with 9 dummy variables from var 2 and 15 in var3):

```
def regression(data, var1, var2, var3):
    for var in var 2:
        for var in var1:
            for var in var3:
                f = '%s ~ %s * %s' % (var1, var2, var3)
                y, x = patsy.dmatrices(f, data, return_type = 'dataframe')
                result = sm.Logit(y,x).fit()
                print(result.summary())
                print(np.exp(result.params))
```

Anyway - I'm trying to get the output to print to something other than the console so I can save it and go through for significant results. I bet the answer isn't difficult, but I'm new to python and statsmodels and haven't seen anything obvious enough in the statsmodels documentation or on stackoverflow.
Thanks

Comment: `with open("outfile-name.txt", "w") as out: sys.stdout = out ...`

Comment: @zondo: I think writing to `sys` is not a good idea :/

Comment: @NeilG: That's true.  I didn't even think about what *you* said.  As long as you're changing each `print()` call anyway, why not use `fileobject.write(...)` instead of `print(..., out=fileobject)`?

Comment: @zondo I'm not sure. Maybe add an alternate answer with an explanation of the differences?

Comment: @NeilG: I have followed out your suggestion.  In the process, I realized why using `print` is easier ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write to a file instead of to stdout, you can open the file and use `.write()`:

```
def regression(...):
    with open("outfile") as out:
        for var in var 2:
            for var in var1:
                for var in var3:
                    ...
                    out.write(str(result.summary()) + "\n")
                    out.write(str(np.exp(result.params)) + "\n)
```

As @NeilG pointed out, you could use `print(result.summary(), out=out)` as well.  That's pretty much a shortcut for `out.write(str(...) + "\n")`  If you want to put `result.summary()` and `np.exp(result.params)` in separate files, use `with open("summary", "w") as summary, open("params", "w") as params:` and use `summary` and `params` instead of `out`.

Comment: Man - as I get more into python I keep finding how simple so many answers are. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this:

```
with open("summary.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(result.summary)
with open("params.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(np.exp(result.params))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do what @zondo says and open a file.  Then pass the file handle into `print` as the `out` parameter.